# Different rendering behaviour with CSS/ SCSS

Tags: html, css, sass

I've tried to integrate [this example](https://codepen.io/mattonit/pen/vLoddq) for some jumping dots as a fallback for lazy loading some other scripts and images.

But if I change the css, as shown in the following example, the last dot looks smaller in my example than the other two dots (smaller width?). By using the same input scss values in my [codepen example](https://codepen.io/reneebeling/pen/QWyyMyL), the dots look as expected:

**This rendering:** [image: This rendering] **Codepen rendering:**  [image]

I've also checked the computed styles and I can only see a difference for the computed height and width values of the span elements.

Why do I see a different rendering in this code example on stackoverflow (and in my localhost node.js example) compared to the example on codepen?

Do I have to look into all parent DOM elements in the codepen example in order to get the missing css part?

```js
class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {};
    
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="wave">
                <span className="dot">
                </span>
                <span className="dot">
                </span>
                <span className="dot">
                </span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
html, body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}

body {
   background:#F6F7F8;
}

div#wave {
   position: relative;
   margin-top: 5vh;
   text-align: center;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}

div#wave .dot {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 6px;
   height: 6px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   margin-right: 6px;
   background: #303131;
   animation: wave 1.3s linear infinite;
}

div#wave .dot:nth-child(2) {
   animation-delay: -1.1s;
}

div#wave .dot:nth-child(3) {
   animation-delay: -0.9s;
}

@keyframes wave {
   0%, 60%, 100% {
      transform: initial;
   }

   30% {
      transform: translateY(-15px);
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='container'></div>
```

I am working with the chrome browser (Version 83.0.4103.97), if this makes any difference.

Comment: Have a look at the CSS the SCSS generates, if it's the same, you can rule that out as a cause (Your codepen link shows a 404 for me so I can't try it) I would probably assume it's a quirk of sub-pixel rendering.

Comment: @DBS thanks for the hint. I changed the link and I hope it will work now.

Comment: @DBS how can I prevent "subpixel rendering" in this example?

Comment: Looks the same for me on Codepen and SO, trying with FF 68.9.0esr and Chromium 80.0.3987.162.

Comment: I counted the pixels of your circles haha, all are 7px, and the last one is 6px wide (the unique right xD): https://imgur.com/t4bg9Pt
This seems to me something when the monitor on windows 10 is scaled up, this gives a lot of pixelart errors on websites too
I changed the scale of my screen to 120%, and the middle circle gets thicker, but if I go back to 100% it will return to normal
I don't know how to adjust this, because it's a failure of windows to try to adjust pixels where they "don't really exist"

Comment: @KevynTuleuDourado Thanks for the investigation. :D I have tried the above code on my iPhone and it looks like expected but I doesn't work on my windows PC.

Comment: If you change the resolution it will back to normal, i will post a most complete answer

Comment: @Paflow Do you work with a windows PC or do you use another OS?

Comment: @Rene Linux it  is

Comment: @Paflow "Same" as error or right way? Do you know if Linux has any screen scale tools?

Comment: @KevynTuleuDourado Both look correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I counted the pixels of your circles, all are 7px, and the last one is 6px wide (theoretically the unique right according your CSS):

[image: pixels count]

This seems to me when the monitor on Windows10 is scaled up (more or less than 100%):
[image: Change scale on Windows10]
https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-custom-display-scaling-setting-windows-10

This gives a lot of pixelart errors on websites too!
I changed the scale of my screen to 120%, and the middle circle gets thicker, but if I go back to 100% it will return to normal.

I've done some pixelart projects, and I've received complaints from some users, and I couldn't reproduce the error, then one day I messed with this windows function and noticed the error, it was the scale of the windows screen, which distorts some pixels by "customizing the scale".

Theoretically it will always give errors with that function, unless it is a multiple of 100%, such as 200% or 300%, because in theory the pixels would not be distorted in size with that values.

I don't know if there is a solution to this, I never found, because it's a failure of windows to try to adjust pixels where they "don't really exist"

Comment: ok, this answer is interesting but why doesn't it happen in the codepen example?

Comment: Good question! Because in the codepen that you provided the circles are much larger, here they have 6px, there they have 12px, so it is much easier to adapt the pixels to the windows image algorithm, is twice the size. When smaller is more easier to the windows scale algorithm make mistakes.
With 6px there is no solution for this problem. Only if you increase the size of the circles.

Comment: if you move horizontally maybe will help, but it will only happen on your specific monitor, windows makes a point of placing a custom scale for each type of screen, and I don't know if it comes from the factory, but if it does, each user will have a problem in a different position when it comes to pixels.
If you use large circles it solves your problem, but imagine when it is a site full of pixelart x.x

Comment: I added a new example [example](https://codepen.io/reneebeling/pen/QWyyMyL)

Comment: My screen with 175% on this new example that you gave: https://imgur.com/Lyv8bDn
(cut right circles). If you take it out of the full screen, maybe the error will appear or not. When I remove from the full screen look what happened with me (at 175%) https://imgur.com/zN80RLj (cut down)

Comment: they may be constant on certain specific occasions, I think it may have to do with the size and position of the window, but I don't know, it's kind of unpredictable when you change the window scale. If you back to 100%, all those errors will disappear.

Comment: Did you notice that maybe some programs are a bit blurry too? Some programs do not support this mode and are all blurred.